# Error: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'ngx-bootstrap/component-loader/component-loader.factory' in 'project path'

Tags: angular

This is a simple server for use in testing or debugging Angular applications locally.
It hasn't been reviewed for security issues.
DON'T USE IT FOR PRODUCTION!

---

✔ Browser application bundle generation complete.

> ./src/app/xxx/xxx.module.ts:38:0-97 - Error: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'ngx-bootstrap/component-loader/component-loader.factory'
> in 'project path'

This is my package.json file and I have install ngx-bootstrap manually but the error was not resolved.

```
  {
  "name": "project-name",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "-": "0.0.1",
    "@angular/animations": "~12.1.4",
    "@angular/cdk": "^12.1.4",
    "@angular/common": "~12.1.4",
    "@angular/compiler": "~12.1.4",
    "@angular/core": "~12.1.4",
    "@angular/forms": "~12.1.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~12.1.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~12.1.4",
    "@angular/router": "~12.1.4",
    "@angular/service-worker": "^12.1.4",
    "@aspnet/signalr": "^1.1.4",
    "@auth0/angular-jwt": "^5.0.2",
    "@fortawesome/angular-fontawesome": "^0.9.0",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^1.2.35",
    "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^5.15.3",
    "angular-datatables": "^12.0.0",
    "bootstrap": "^5.0.2",
    "datatables.net": "^1.10.25",
    "datatables.net-dt": "^1.10.21",
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
    "jquery": "^3.6.0",
    "moment": "^2.29.1",
    "ng-sidebar": "^9.4.2",
    "ng2-tooltip-directive": "^2.10.3",
    "ngx-bootstrap": "^7.0.0",
    "ngx-pagination": "^5.1.1",
    "ngx-perfect-scrollbar": "^10.1.1",
    "ngx-spinner": "^12.0.0",
    "ngx-toastr": "^14.0.0",
    "primeicons": "^4.1.0",
    "primeng": "^12.0.1",
    "rxjs": "~7.3.0",
    "rxjs-compat": "^6.6.7",
    "save": "^2.4.0",
    "tslib": "^2.3.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.11.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^12.1.4",
    "@angular/cli": "~12.1.4",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~12.1.4",
    "@types/datatables.net": "^1.10.20",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.8.2",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.10",
    "@types/jquery": "^3.5.6",
    "@types/node": "^16.4.11",
    "codelyzer": "^6.0.2",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.8.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~7.0.0",
    "karma": "~6.3.4",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~3.0.3",
    "karma-jasmine": "~4.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.7.0",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.12",
    "protractor": "~7.0.0",
    "ts-node": "~10.1.0",
    "tslint": "~6.1.0",
    "typescript": "~4.3.5"
  },
```

Comment: Do you import `ngx-bootstrap` in any component/module in your project? Meanwhile, you may try `npm install` to reinstall packages and restart the Angular App. Fingers crossed.

Comment: i had added TooltipModule.forRoot() in @ngModule imports and import { TooltipModule } from 'ngx-bootstrap/tooltip';
 in my app.module . Also npm install but showing same error.

Comment: You may try to remove `import { TooltipModule } from 'ngx-bootstrap/tooltip' and `imports: [TooltipModule.forRoot()]` from app.module. Next restart Angular App to see the same error happened or not to make sure there is no dependency from app.module.ts.

Comment: Meanwhile, I saw you install `ng2-tooltip-directive` as this package also offer `TooltipModule`. Either you use `TooltipModule` from this package or remove it if it is not used.